# Correlator of Energy momentum tensor for Free bosons under Twisted boundary Condition in Conformal Field Theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I had a doubt in the Yellow book by Francesco et al, pertaining to equation 6.85 on page 166.

Now, energy momentum is defined by
\begin{equation}
T(z) = -2 \pi g  \ lim_{w \to z}(\partial\phi(z)\partial\phi(w) - \left <\partial\phi(z)\partial\phi(w) \right>) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   (1)         \end{equation}
It has been shown in the book that
\begin{equation}
\left <\partial\phi(z)\partial\phi(w) \right > = -\frac{1}{(z-w)^2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   (2)
\end{equation}
for periodic case and
\begin{equation}
\left <\partial\phi(z)\partial\phi(w) \right > = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{z}{w}} + \sqrt{\frac{w}{z}}}{(z-w)^2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   (3)
\end{equation}
for the case of twisted boundary conditions. I am unable to understand why the correlator, $\left <T(z) \right >$ will not be zero in both cases. When we take the correlator, the second term remains unchanged, in equation 1 above, as it is independent of $\phi$. The first term becomes exactly the second term. So they should cancel out, to give $\left <T(z) \right > = 0$. However, the book says

\begin{equation}
\left <T(z) \right > = \frac{1}{16z^2}
\end{equation}
This is equation 6.85 on page 166 of the book.

Comment: The two-point function being subtracted as a counterterm in (1) should be the periodic one in both cases.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Yes that is true. Any reason why the counterterm is periodic in both cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct definition of the stress tensor is
$$
T(z) = - 2\pi g \lim_{w \to z}  \left( \partial \phi (z) \partial \phi(w) + \frac{1}{ ( z - w )^2 } \right)
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\langle T(z) \rangle_{periodic} &= - 2\pi g \lim_{w \to z}  \left( \langle \partial \phi (z) \partial \phi(w)\rangle_{periodic} + \frac{1}{ ( z - w )^2 } \right) \\
&= - 2\pi g \lim_{w \to z}  \left( - \frac{1}{(z-w)^2}  + \frac{1}{ ( z - w )^2 } \right) \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
On the other hand
\begin{align}
\langle T(z) \rangle_{anti-periodic} &= - 2\pi g \lim_{w \to z}  \left( \langle \partial \phi (z) \partial \phi(w)\rangle_{anti-periodic} + \frac{1}{ ( z - w )^2 } \right) \\
&= - 2\pi g \lim_{w \to z}  \left( -  \frac{1}{2} \frac{ \sqrt{z/w} + \sqrt{w/z} }{ ( z - w )^2 }   + \frac{1}{ ( z - w )^2 } \right) \\
&= 4\pi g \frac{1}{16z^2} 
\end{align}
which matches the result of the yellow book.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I understood the steps following your definition. But from where do we get the definition of the stress tensor that you have used above ? I found the definition that I used in the Yellow book (Eq 5.80). Similar definition has been used for the free Fermion.

Comment: That equation only holds in the free theory. We do not want to change the definition of the operator in the two cases. All we are changing are the boundary conditions, NOT the operator itself. The definition of the operator is FIXED in the first line of the answer. Then, with this fixed definition, we can evaluate its correlator in different models with different boundary conditions.